# Docker MySQL = exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error

Tags: wordpress, docker, portainer

i try to install wordpress with portainer and i have this error message : exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error about the MySQL container.

I new with docker and i'm lost.

Can you help me please ?

I restart de container.
I install new instance.

Comment: Sharing the docker config will help to find the issue. or You can also check the [Docker exec format error – How we sort it out?](https://bobcares.com/blog/docker-exec-format-error/) article to solve the issue, or check some other solutions for the specific error code suggested on other websites.

Comment: thks, i resolve my problem, i just change the version of mysql on my docker file to lastest and it's work fine !!!